Can't upgrade Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 but I never get to update to a newer distribution.
sudo apt update says all packages are up to date.
sudo apt upgrade says 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
sudo do-release-upgrade says Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
How is that possible? Shouldn't I be prompted to update to Ubuntu 23 or 24?
If I try sudo do-release-upgrade -d, as suggested in Unable to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 22.04 to 24.04.1, I get:
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only
available from the latest supported release.
Thanks.

This question is similar to: Unable to upgrade from Ubuntu Server 22.04 to 24.04.1. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The -d will now attempt to upgrade you to 24.10 from 24.04, which is NOT what you're trying to do thus the error message you're getting. I suggest waiting for a few days, as the last I heard was the upgrade is expected to open during the week (Alex Murray of Ubuntu Security Team on latest Ubuntu Security Podcast episode)

Hi. After waiting a few days it indeed prompted me to upgrade to 24.04. Thank you!
